# With OOP inheritance how do I keep the amount of parameters low in a 'child' class

Tags: c#, oop

So with inheritance I always find my self dealing with extremely long constructors in the most specific classes. I am looking for a paradigm or method by which I can avoid this problem. I've thought of using factories, but if I did, I would still have to use the constructor in the factory. Regardless of that thought, is there anything I can do to keep constructor parameter length down?

For example:

```
abstract class DrawableComponent : Component, ITransformable, IScalable, IDrawable, IRotatable
```

Is a child class with a constructor like

```
DrawableComponent(string Name, int SizeX, int SizeY, int X, int Y, float Rotation) : base(Name) { ... }
```

Now let's say I'd like to make a child of that. Things just get more complex and ugly.

```
class TextBoxComponent : DrawableComponent, IRenderable
```

The constructor now gets extremely long:

```
public TextBoxComponent(
    IDrawableUnit Background,
    IDrawableUnit Text,
    string Name,
    int X,
    int Y,
    int SX,
    int SY)
: base(Name, SX,SY,X,Y,0.0f)
{
    this.Background = Background;
    this.Foreground = Foreground;
}
```

---

In summary of this, I'm sick of having things like this:

```
class Blah {Blah(blah)}
class childBlah : Blah {childBlah(blah,blahs,blaha) : base (blah)}
class grandChildBlah : childBlah {grandChildBlah(blah, blahs, blaha, blaht, blauh) : base(blah,blahs,blaha) }
```

Comment: Extremely long constructors doing what, exactly?

Comment: Use your favourite IoC container / DI framework. This is one of the many issues dependency injection solves.

Comment: @Kane - while constructor DI solves issues for classes that need "services", it doesn't solve anything for constructors that take values such as the one in the example.

Comment: @Lucero, completely agree - the question didn't include the example when I posted the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have really long constructor parameter lists, then you must have many fields in a single class? This indicates that you should think about splitting those classes into more than one class, or extracting groups of related fields into their own types.

For example, x and y coordinate fields or width and height values:

```
private double mX;
private double mY;
private double mWidth;
private double mHeight;
```

should really be a single point or vector or rectangle object:

```
private vector mPosition;
private vector mSize;

// or

private rectangle mRegion;
```

Another suggestion might be to reduce your inheritance, and instead use composition. Instead of an **is-a** relationship, use a **has-a** relationship:

Your 'blah' example then becomes something like:

```
class Blah
{
   Blah(int blah) { ... }
}

class ChildBlah
{
   Blah mBlah;
   ...
   ChildBlah(Blah blah, int blahs, int blaha)
   { mBlah = blah; ... }
}

class GrandChildBlah
{
   ChildBlah mChildBlah;
   ...
   GrandChildBlah(ChildBlah blah, int blaht, int blahu)
   { mChildBlah = blah; ... }
}
```

Comment: +1 for composition. Inheritance often seems like the way but ends up being a headache. Keep classes - even inherited, child classes - simple.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the Builder pattern. At the very least, this would limit calls to the constructor to one class. For example:

```
VehicleBuilder builder = new VehicleBuilder();
builder.setColor( Color.Green );
builder.setEngineSize( EngineSize.Size1500 );
builder.setWheelSize( 14 );
Vehicle auto = builder.makeVehicle();
```

Another possibility is to divide some of those parameters into classes. Even if you're creating an immutable object, it can be fed mutable parameters, if you make defensive copies.

```
VehicleParameters parameters = new VehicleParameters();
parameters.setColor( Color.Green );
parameters.setEngineSize( EngineSize.Size1500 );
parameters.setWheelSize( 14 );
Vehicle auto = new Vehicle( parameters );
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you can do.  Either [constructor chaining](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/e15be817-42d2-4600-82e6-46d5081858b7/), or [optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Constructor chaining essentially means you have a default constructor, and then one more constructor for each additional parameter, or as required.

Like so:

```
class Class1
{
    private string name, jobTitle, address;

    public Class1(string name, string title) 
        : this(name, title, "my default address") {}

    public Class1(string name, string jobTitle, string address)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

The other option is optional parameters, like so:

```
class Class1
{
    private string name, jobTitle, address;

    public Class1(string name = "default", string jobTitle = "defaultJob", string address = "defaultAddress")
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that required parameters must always come before optional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can ease the pain by passing in a dictionary of key-value pairs that hold the attributes you're interested in. For better readability and syntax, this dictionary can be build from an anonymous class, just like libraries like ASP.NET MVC do it for a lot of method calls.

You'd then have two constructors at each level: a protected taking the dictionary and a public one taking the anonymous object, which itself would always call the protected constructor with the anonymous object transformed into the dictionary.

```
public class Class1 {
  public Class1(object args): this(new RouteValueDictionary(args)) {}

  protected Class1(RouteValueDictionary args) {
    // retrieve any property you need here from args
  }
}

public class Class2: Class1 {
  public Class2(object args): this(new RouteValueDictionary(args)) {}

  protected Class2(RouteValueDictionary args): base(args) {
    // retrieve any property specific to Class2 from args
  }
}

// etc.
```

Use this like that:

```
new Class2(new {
    X: 10,
    Y: 20,
    Name: "instance"
  });
```

The advantage is that this gives you a nice syntax no matter how many args are passed in, and you can also omit arguments or create very dynamic "overloads" of the constructor. The main issue of this approach is that the compiler cannot tell you at compile time what needs to be passed into the constructor (e.g. you loose some of the static analysis benefits).

Note: the [`RouteValueDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx) used here for parsing is not part of the MVC project, but of the System.Web assembly, so that it is readily available everywhere where the full .NET framework has been deployed. It does handle the anonymous type extraction efficiently, usually better than reflecting it manually yourself.